# Ollydbg| Inconsistent results as compared to the stack view pane

Tags: ollydbg, ollyscript

I've been trying to apply hooks on Win32 `ReadFile` so I can read the buffer and the params,however am not even sure whether the output is correct since it doesn't matchup with the stack-view pane nor the input.

If anyone can confirm whether am doing it right I'll be most thankful.

I cannot test this code properly atm since the modem I was using got bricked. Using local files as input for `Readfile` is giving me junk output in the log window.

Script

```
// === break on load module ===
mov sApi, "ReadFile"
mov sDLL, "kernel32"
gpa sApi, sDLL

// store address
mov handle, $RESULT
log handle
        cmp handle, 0
je abort



lbl_bp:
// run
go handle

    mov adrRet, [esp]
    mov hFile, [esp+4.]
    mov InBuffer,  [esp+8.]
    mov nNumberOfBytesToRead, [esp+12.]
    mov lpNumberOfBytesRead, [esp+16.]
    mov lpOverlapped, [esp+20.]

    log InBuffer
    log hFile
    log nNumberOfBytesToRead
    log lpNumberOfBytesRead
    log lpOverlapped

    cmp InBuffer,0
    je noIn 

    mov INN, [InBuffer], nNumberOfBytesToRead
    log INN



    jmp lbl_bp

 noIn:  
    jmp lbl_bp

abort:
```

Answer (score 1):

It works !.
I just used a different api  function. But don't use the above where there is no input, as the `nNumberOfBytesToRead` will cause olly to allocate an unknown size of memory since the variable has not been initialized, hence the crashes.
Or at-least initialize the variable before using it.